# Prevent Blank Select in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I updating a form to angular. The selects in it are not generated by angular. I am using angular to add some interactivity and submit the form. I am having an issue where angular is adding a blank select to the element. Is there a way of preventing this without having angular generate the select?

```
<select name="inventory_status" ng-model="formData.inventory_status">
<option ng-selected="true" ng-value="1">Active</option>
<option ng-value="2">Discontinued</option>
<option ng-value="3">Special Order</option>     
<option ng-value="4">Pre-Order</option> 
</select>
```

The above code produces this:

```
<select name="inventory_status" ng-model="formData.inventory_status" ng-init="sortorder='1'" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"><option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
        <option ng-selected="true" ng-value="1" value="1" selected="selected">Active</option>
        <option ng-value="2" value="2">Discontinued</option>
        <option ng-value="3" value="3">Special Order</option>       
        <option ng-value="4" value="4">Pre-Order</option>   
        </select>
```

My hope is to not have this produced:

```
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
```

Additionally I would like to not have to use angular to generate the dropdown although if that is the only option I could. This only happens when I set this field to `ng-model`. I am setting it to `ng-model` because I want to use angular to submit the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the initial value of formData.inventory_status? If that is set to a valid value, the empty option should not show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `$scope.formData.inventory_status = 1` or whatever value you want selected and it will not show the empty option, plus you don't need `ng-selected` if you set the value.

Comment: I tried this and got an error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'inventory_status' of undefined

Comment: I don't know how the rest of your code is, but if you have 'formData' defined  it will work. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cw5tsrna/

Comment: You are correct! Two things I was missing. I wasn't paying attention to where I declared the formdata array and tried to set the status before declaring the array. Thanks!